# C++ Class with Dynamic Memory Allocation - Why am I getting this error?

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm making a class called DblArray, and doing basic functions for it. I seem to be getting a problem when compiling, though, as it says "incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed." I'll post all of my code  below, but I think the problem is happening in this function:

```
void DblArray::insertVal(double n)
{
  if ( size == capacity )
  {
    capacity *= 2;
    double temp[size];

    for ( int i = 0; i < size; i++ )
      temp[i] = data[i];
    delete [] data;
    data = 0;

    data = new double[capacity];
    for ( int i = 0; i < size; i++ )
      data[i] = temp[i];
  }
  size++;
  data[size] = n;
}
```

The header file is this:

```
#include <iostream>

#ifndef DBLARRAY_H
#define DBLARRAY_H

class DblArray
{
private:
  long capacity;
  long size;
  double * data;
public:
  DblArray();
  ~DblArray();
  DblArray(const DblArray& d);
  DblArray& operator = (const DblArray& d);

  double operator [] (int i);
  long getCapacity();
  long getSize();
  double getAverage();
  void insertVal(double);
  void removeVal();
};

#endif // DBLARRAY_H
```

The implementation file is this:

```
#include "DblArray.h"

DblArray::DblArray()
{
  capacity = 1;
  size = 0;
  data = new double[capacity];
}

DblArray::~DblArray()
{
  capacity = 0;
  size = 0;
  delete [] data;
  data = NULL;
}

DblArray::DblArray(const DblArray& d)
{
  capacity = d.capacity;
  size = d.size;
  data = new double[capacity];

  for ( int i = 0; i < size; i++ )
  {
    data[i] = d.data[i];
  }
}

DblArray& DblArray::operator = (const DblArray& d)
{
  DblArray dNew;
  dNew.capacity = d.capacity;
  dNew.size = d.size;
  dNew.data = new double[capacity];

  for ( int i = 0; i < dNew.size; i++ )
  {
    dNew.data[i] = d.data[i];
  }

  return dNew;
}

double DblArray::operator [] (int i)
{
  return data[i];
}

long DblArray::getCapacity()
{
  return capacity;
}

long DblArray::getSize()
{
  return size;
}

double DblArray::getAverage()
{
  double average = 0;
  for ( int i = 0; i < size; i++ )
  {
    average += data[i];
  }
  average = average / size;

  return average;
}

void DblArray::insertVal(double n)
{
  if ( size == capacity )
  {
    capacity *= 2;
    double temp[size];

    for ( int i = 0; i < size; i++ )
      temp[i] = data[i];
    delete [] data;
    data = 0;

    data = new double[capacity];
    for ( int i = 0; i < size; i++ )
      data[i] = temp[i];
  }
  size++;
  data[size] = n;
}

void DblArray::removeVal()
{
  data[size] = 0;
}
```

And the driver is this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "DblArray.h"

using namespace std;

DblArray print( DblArray );

int main()
{
  //Data abstractions
  DblArray d1;

  //Printing the contents of d1 before testing functions
  print(d1);

  for ( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
  {
    d1.insertVal(i);
  }

  //Printing contents of d1 after adding values
  print(d1);

  return 0;
}

//Function to print the contents of each object
DblArray print( DblArray d )
{
  cout << "Capacity:\t" << d.getCapacity() << endl;
  cout << "Size:\t" << d.getSize() << endl;
  cout << "Data:\t" << endl;
  for ( int i = 0; i < d.getSize(); i++ )
  {
    cout << d[i] << "\t";
  }
  cout << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Please post a [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

In `insertVal()`,

```
size++;
data[size] = n;
```

should be changed into

```
data[size++] = n;
```

Otherwise, when `size == capacity-1`, the `data[size] = n;` writes out of array boundary. The same issue also happens in `removeVal()`.

Also the semantic of your `operator=()` is strange. It doesn't modify `this` at all, and returning reference to local object is wrong. Usually it should look like:

```
DblArray& DblArray::operator=(const DblArray& rhs) {
    if (this == &rhs) return *this;
    delete [] data;
    data = new double[rhs.capacity];
    capacity = rhs.capacity;
    size = rhs.size;
    // copy rhs.data[0] .. rhs.data[size-1] into data[]
    return *this;
}
```

or define `DblArray::swap()` and perform copy-and-swap idiom.

Comment: how should I change the `operator=( )`?

Comment: Okay I changed my operator=( ), but now I'm still having problems with insertVal. I changed it to what you said because it definitely makes sense, but it's still not working correctly, and I'm getting this error now:
"malloc: *** error for object 0x7fff51843b80: pointer being freed was not allocated"

Comment: @IvyBlalock Please run it through debugger to see where the error happened. If it does not happen when debug info is inserted, run it through valgrind to see if there is any error.

Answer (score 0):

You have:

> if ( size == capacity )

then you allocate:

> data = new double[capacity];

so data is of size `size`. In the end you have:

> size++;
>   data[size] = n;

this is writing outside array bounds and is the cause of undefined behaviour which can result in error you are getting

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few problems in your source here, two that instantly sprang to me are as follows:

The function with the signature `DblArray print(DblArray)` does not return a value. You should change the signature to match the actual behaviour and you should also consider passing `DblArray` as a reference: `void print(const DblArray& d)`

The other issues I found have been raised by other answers. Out of curiosity, which compiler and platform are you using? Consider pasting your code in to an online compiler every now and then, gcc and clang tend to be very good with warnings if you are running in a Windows build environment. In particular, I use [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/). You can customise the compiler flags to show more, or less warnings, and so on. With your example, you should be able to just paste everything you have written here, removing any `#include <DblArray.h>` directives, and be good to go.